# how to upload CodeIgniter website on server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

I just created a website in CodeIgniter. And it is working fine on localhost {for eg: localhost/project_name/controller_name} but after uploading it to the server{for eg: www.domain_name.com/project_name/controller_name} it is showing ERROR 404. 
what I do is simply make a zip file of the project and then extract it on the server.Please guide me if I am doing it in wrong way.

Comment: Edit the question to include your `htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Possible you using development on windows, where you specify the controller in lower characters, now on web server is linux which is case sensitive, you might need to rename your controller, and make its first letter capital

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed the base url according to your domain and database related configuration (database name, user name and password) also.